# How do I find the slope (m) for a line given a point (x,y) on the line and the line's angle from the y axis in python?

Tags: python, math

I understand that the equation for a straight line is:
y = (m * x) + c
where m is the slope of the line which would be (ydelta/xdelta) but I dont know how to get this value when I only know a single point and an angle rather than two points.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I know a point and an angle. I've edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just a single point (and nothing else) you cannot solve such a problem, there are infinitely many lines going through a single point.

If you know the **angle to x axis** then simply `m=tan(angle)` (you do not need any points to do that, point is only required to figure out `c` value, which should now be simple).

To convert angle from the y-axis to the x-axis simply compute `pi/2 - angle`

Comment: I know the line's angle from the Y axis in degrees I just need to know how to convert degrees into a gradient

Comment: than you incorrectly wrote the question, please reformulate it.

Comment: I mention that I know the angle in the main top line of the question

Comment: `tan` is a good approach, although I think you need to give it the angle with respect to the x axis, while the OP has the angle with respect to the Y axis.

Comment: @Kevin You would just subtract from 90 (or pi/2, depending on the units your angle is given in).

Comment: Then cot(angle) = rise/run.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line is `y = mx + c`.
You are given a point on this line, and the angle of this line from the y-axis.
The gradient `m` will be `math.cot(angle_in_radians)`. The x and y values will be the same as your given point. To find `c`, simply evaluate `y - mx`.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, let's say your point is `(x,y)=(1,2)`

Then you want to solve `2 = m + c`. Obviously there is no way you can do this.

Comment: @Scorpion_God Do you know his original question does not contain `I only know a single point and an angle rather than two points` but `how to get this value when I only know one point`???

Comment: @Scorpion_God Fine, whatever

Comment: @Scorpion_God such discussion is meaningless. believe it or not when I saw the question is doesn't say anything about angle. Another thing, don't reply.